# Dynamically Generate and show Table in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating my first app on android, accordingly I have low experience to develop android apps and I'm fist time use java too.

**What I want ?**
I want to generate table from ArrayList

**What's the problem ?**
I have problem when I generate table. When "for" loop finished debugger stands in catch block (but when I mouse over "e", it writes - "local variable e is not defined" and I can not read some error)  after that I see on phone screen -"unfortunately app is closed"

**What's happen without For Loop ?**
Without For loop everything works well, when I try to show only one object.

[image]

Please help and give me suggestions, Thanx.

**Hare is Java code:**

```
try {
    ArrayList<Persons> otherPersons = new ArrayList<Persons>();
    otherPerosons = GetPersonsList();//from service

                 //  /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
                TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamictable);

                TextView[] title = new TextView[1000];
                TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[1000];
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams trparams;
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams titleparams;

                for (int y=0; y < otherPersons.size(); y++) {
                    /* Create a new row to be added. */
                    tr[y] = new TableRow(this);
                    tr[y].setId(y+100);
                    tr[y].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    trparams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tr[y].getLayoutParams();
                    trparams.setMargins(0, 8, 0, 5); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    tr[y].setLayoutParams(trparams);

                   /* Create a TextView to be the row-content. */
                    title[y] = new TextView(this);
                    title[y].setText(otherPersons.get(y).Name);
                    title[y].setId(y +200);
                    title[y].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    title[y].setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    title[y].setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 34));
                    titleparams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) title[y].getLayoutParams();
                    titleparams.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    title[y].setLayoutParams(titleparams);


                    tr[y].addView(title[y]);

                  /* Add row to TableLayout. */

                  tl.addView(tr[y], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }


             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Hare is my Design XML:**

```
 <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dynamictable"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:shrinkColumns="*"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
                    android:stretchColumns="*"
                    android:background="#ffB224">


                </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but try to put your exception-output in your logcat output with

```
try{

}catch(Exception e){
  Log.e("ClassName", e.toString());
}
```

Maybe you see more information about the exception.

Here you can find more information about [Android Logging](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: thank you for reply, but there are nothing in Logcat.